# Only one neko file

Tags: haxe, neko

I'm trying to call an URL (e.g : `http://localhost:2000/index.n/test`), but the server will try to find test.n like that, and I would like to go in index.n file and get index.n/test as request's path. How could I do that please ? **(I'm using Haxe)**

(in PHP it works)

Thank you very much,
Peekmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using `nekotools server` to test your neko scripts, you will need to launch it with `nekotools server -rewrite`.  If you're using apache, you will need to use mod_rewrite.